# Load a Grid from a text file in python

Tags: python, arrays, file

I have a problem with the code below. I wanted to read a text.file from python which returns a grid corresponding to the data contained in the
file named file.  Here is the code:

```
import csv

def loadGrid(file):
with open("C:\ Users\ Desktop\ file.txt") as file:
    grid = []
for gridLines in csv.reader(file):
    # The rstrip method gets rid of the "\n" at the end of each line
    grid.append(gridLines.rstrip().split("[]"))

loadGrid(file)
```

I am getting this error, i have been trying to look for a solution but to no avail.

**NameError: name 'file' is not defined**

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are inputting the variable *file* into your function, but the variable does not exist so you are getting an error. Also once inputted the variable isn't used. I think what you are trying to do is import a file of a specific name, you can do that like this:

```
import csv

def loadGrid(filename):
    with open("C:\ Users\ Desktop\ {0}".format(filename)) as file:
        grid = []
    for gridLines in csv.reader(file):
        # The rstrip method gets rid of the "\n" at the end of each line
        grid.append(gridLines.rstrip().split("[]"))

file = "test.txt"
loadGrid(file)
```